# basic reference for stacks

Tags: coherent-sheaves, topological-stacks

I'd like a reference for a very  basic definition of stacks
Kashiwara's paper almost does it
except for example writing such as
for every open set U in the cover there is a cat C(U)
so U --> C(U) is a functor to the category of categories?

Answer (score 4):

Dear professor Stasheff,

I suggest you the following papers:

1. Barbara Fantechi - Stacks for everybody, available at [professor Rehmann's home page](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~rehmann/ECM/cdrom/3ecm/pdfs/pant3/fantechi.pdf);
2. Tomás L. Gómez - Algebraic stacks, available at [arxiv.org](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911199);
3. Angelo Vistoli - Notes on Grothendieck topologies, fibered categories and descent theory, available at [arxiv.org](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0412512).

I hope I was helpful,

best regards.

Armando